# Find the resulting speed and direction

Tags: trigonometry

A barge is pulled by two tugboats. The first tugboat is traveling at a
speed of 15 knots with heading 130°, and the second tugboat is traveling at a speed of
16 knots with heading 190°. Find the resulting speed and direction of the barge.

I can do the problems involving one force acting, but the two forces acting are throwing me off...would someone care to help please?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Suppose only one force was acting, then you can find the x component and y component of the velocities. If there are two forces, then you will have a second x component and a second y component. All you have to do is add up all the x components to make your final x component and add up all the y components to make your final y component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mathguy has helpfully pointed out, you need to resolve both velocities into the $x$ and $y$ components.

The figure below should help you to resolve the velocities.

[image]

By trigonometry (using the convention that East/right is positive), the overall horizontal component is given by
 $$x_v=15\cos(40^\circ)-16\cos(80^\circ)=8.7123$$
So the barge is heading in an easterly direction.

Using the convention that North/up is positive, the overall vertical component is given by
$$y_v=-15\sin(40^\circ)-16\sin(80^\circ)=-25.399$$
So the barge is heading in a southerly direction.

Using Pythagoras, the resultant speed of the barge is given by
$$\sqrt{8.7123^2+(-25.399)^2}=26.851$$

As for the direction in which the barge is travelling, the clockwise  angle with respect to the East axis will be $$\arctan\left(\frac{25.399}{8.7123}\right)=71.1^\circ$$
resulting in a heading of $161.1^\circ$

Comment: That was very helpful thank you!! I was a little confused by the equation you used to find the x and y velocities though, I don't recognize it. Also, what's the reasoning behind starting from the East axis when calculating the heading? If you hadn't explained it I would have started from the North axis. appreciate your time in helping me out!

Comment: The x velocity is basically the horizontal (West-East) direction component, and the y velocity is the vertical (North-South) component. There is more than one way of finding the x and y velocity. For example, for the $x$ velocity, the equation $15\sin 50^\circ-16\sin 10^\circ$ would have been equally valid. In terms of the heading, because I found that the final x-velocity was in the East direction, and the final y-velocity was in the South direction, I created a right angle triangle, one of whose side was the East axis.